# Compare an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to compare an image in javascript. If the image is true it will change to a different image. I wrote an if statement but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

```
function test()
{
imageElement = document.getElementById('pic');
if(imageElement.src == "images/cat_12.gif"){

imageElement.src = "images/press2_12.gif";
}else{

}
}
```

Comment: Well, what does `imageElement.src` contain?

Comment: @Pekka The fully qualified URL I assume... `.getAttribute('src')` would make it work I think.

Comment: <td><img src="images/topknobs_12.gif" width="468" name="pic" id="pic" height="575" onclick="test();"/></td>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function test(){
    if(imageElement.src.indexOf("images/cat_12.gif") != -1){
       //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`src` will be converted to full URL when you read it from Javascript. You may try to extract the filename instead, e.g. `img.src.substr(img.src.lastIndexOf('/'))`.

A better solution would be use classes and CSS background switch between images.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work function test()
{
img = document.getElementById('pic');
if(img.src.indexOf('images/cat_12.gif')){

imageElement.src = "images/press2_12.gif";
}else{

}
}

Comment: And img.src.substr(img.src.lastIndexOf('/')) doesn't work either it lets all the images through as if the if doesn't apply.

Comment: please supply another solution