# Javascript stop working after first click

Tags: javascript, html

i tried to change the direction of the arrow by changing the scr of the image. 
"www.bsbbalulstudentilorbucuresteni.ro/index" you can see here the problem.

```
<img id="hnav" src="img/down-arrow.svg" class="icon-hnav" onclick="myFunction()">

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
  var x = document.getElementById("hnav");
  if (x.style.bottom === "5px") {
    x.style.bottom = "50px";
  } else {
    x.style.bottom = "5px";
  }
  var x = document.getElementById("hnav");
   if (x.src === "img/up-arrow.svg") {
    x.src = "img/down-arrow.svg";
  } else {
    x.src = "img/up-arrow.svg";
  }
}
```

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you verified that the `if/else` block is being executed as expected? What exactly is wrong, is it just not changing the image?

Comment: Is <img id="hnav" inside <div id="myDIV"? If so its hiding it

Comment: On a related topic, you should be using CSS styles and classes, and wrapper elements. By having all these styles associated with a class and then adding or removing a class on click, you'll greatly simplify your javascript and have your styles in the CSS where they belong and are easier to manipulate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare an image in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922419/compare-an-image-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The `src` *property* of an element will return the full path:

```js
img.src = 'foo.png';
console.log(img.src);
```

```html
<img id="img">
```

So, on further clicks, either check against the full path:

```
if (x.src === "http://www.bsbbalulstudentilorbucuresteni.ro/img/up-arrow.svg") {
```

or check against the src attribute instead:

```
if (x.getAttribute('src') === "img/up-arrow.svg") {
```

```js
img.src = 'foo.png';
console.log(img.getAttribute('src'));
```

```html
<img id="img">
```

Comment: @VlWWv When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

The property `src` is not the same as the attribute of `src`. So `x.src` is now `"http://www.bsbbalulstudentilorbucuresteni.ro/img/down-arrow.svg"`.

You can get the value you expect with `x.getAttribute('src')`. The code will be like:

```
var x = document.getElementById("hnav");
if (x.getAttribute('src') === "img/up-arrow.svg") {
  x.src = "img/down-arrow.svg";
} else {
  x.src = "img/up-arrow.svg";
}
```